# How to make a reusable controller in express/node app

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am using express and axios for http 
I have a controller that receives data from multiple sources by making POST calls(example shown below). I want to make the controller readable and make each API call reusable and separate by function, how can i do that?

```
exports.createApplication= async (req, res) => {

  const financial = await axios.post(
    process.env.SOLIQ_PATH + "finreport",
    {
      lang: "uz",
      tin: tin,
      year: year,
      period: 4,
    },
  );

  const accounting = await axios.post(
    process.env.SOLIQ_PATH + "buxbalans",
    {
      lang: "uz",
      tin: tin,
      year: year,
      period: "4",
    },
    }
  );
};
```

How can i make a custom function that is going to do POST call on its own and returns me the data that was returned by POST call?
What I have tried: I created a file:

```
    const axios = require("axios");
    
    /**
     * 1 - form 1 - accounting report
     * 2 - form 2 - financial report
     */
    
    module.exports = async (reportType, tin, year, period) => {
      let url;
      if (reportType === 1) url = process.env.SOLIQ_PATH + "buxbalans";
      else if (reportType === 2) url = process.env.SOLIQ_PATH + "finreport";
      else throw new Error("Report type of Soliq is not defined");
    
      const report = await axios.post(
        url,
        {
          lang: "uz",
          tin: tin,
          year: year,
          period: period,
        },
        {
          auth: {
            username: process.env.SOLIQ_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.SOLIQ_PASSWORD,
          },
        }
      );
    
      /* validating the report result */
      if (!report.data.success) {
        throw new Error("Error while trying to access data from SOLIQ");
      }
    
      return report.data;

};
```

And called this function in a controller like this:

```
const financial = soliq(2, body.tin, body.soliq_year, body.soliq_period);
const accounting = soliq(1, body.tin, body.soliq_year, body.soliq_period);
```

It is not working.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `const financial = await soliq(2, ...)`?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen true, thanx. what a mistake LOL